# What tools exist for YAML templating with control flow and iteration in Node.js?

Tags: templates, yaml, handlebars.js, interpolation

I am looking to implement something like [these YAML "templates"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) (which appear to use Handlebars syntax). An example is:

```
# File: start.yml
parameters:
- name: buildSteps # the name of the parameter is buildSteps
  type: stepList # data type is StepList
  default: [] # default value of buildSteps
stages:
- stage: secure_buildstage
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest
  jobs:
  - job: secure_buildjob
    steps:
    - script: echo This happens before code 
      displayName: 'Base: Pre-build'
    - script: echo Building
      displayName: 'Base: Build'

    - ${{ each step in parameters.buildSteps }}:
      - ${{ each pair in step }}:
          ${{ if ne(pair.value, 'CmdLine@2') }}:
            ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}       
          ${{ if eq(pair.value, 'CmdLine@2') }}: 
            # Step is rejected by raising a YAML syntax error: Unexpected value 'CmdLine@2'
            '${{ pair.value }}': error         

    - script: echo This happens after code
      displayName: 'Base: Signing'
```

How do they parse this YAML file and pass in the parameters and evaluate the code portions? Is there some framework or library for this? Searching around for "YAML templating" I didn't find much on how this is done. [GitHub actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/quickstart) and CircleCI also use this variable interpolation to some degree in their systems too.

```
name: GitHub Actions Demo
on: [push]
jobs:
  Explore-GitHub-Actions:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo " The job was automatically triggered by a ${{ github.event_name }} event."
      - run: echo " This job is now running on a ${{ runner.os }} server hosted by GitHub!"
      - run: echo " The name of your branch is ${{ github.ref }} and your repository is ${{ github.repository }}."
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: echo " The ${{ github.repository }} repository has been cloned to the runner."
      - run: echo "️ The workflow is now ready to test your code on the runner."
      - name: List files in the repository
        run: |
          ls ${{ github.workspace }}
      - run: echo " This job's status is ${{ job.status }}."
```

What are the Node.js tools used to handle such interpolation?

Note: I am not looking to use Azure YAML templates, or GitHub Actions, etc.. I want to build some random framework which uses YAML and templates *like* these projects, so want to know how they are doing it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops

Comment: [Jinga](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) is another popular templating tool, making use of the double mustache syntax.  Not only does it support value substitution, but it also incorporates flow control (eg, `for` loops, `if` conditions, etc).  In fact, tools like [Ansible incorporate Jinga](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_templating.html) as part of their architecture...